# IE11 doesn't display google fonts (only polish signs) properly

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, google-fonts

I use Fira-sans, sans-serif and polish signs doesn't work on IE 11. My code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,300i,400,500,600,700,800&subset=latin,latin-ext">
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/how-to-make-google-fonts-work-in-ie?

Answer (score 0):

Adding subset=latin-ext for object helped

```
   WebFontConfig = {
                    google: {
                        families: [
                            'Fira Sans:300,300i,400,500,600&subset=latin-ext'
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and this is my sample code.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:300,300i,400,500,600,700,800&subset=latin,latin-ext">
<style>
    h1 {
        font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    }
</style>

 <h1>Większość szkoleń prowadzę</h1>
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fbuzrmL5/

You could see it works well.
[image: The running result in IE11]

Could you show your issue with a screenshot or describe in detail?

Or you could refer to this link:[How to make this Google Font work on Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731808/how-to-make-this-google-font-work-on-internet-explorer-11)

> From google fonts: "Note: For best display in IE, make the stylesheet tag the first element in the HTML section. In IE, if the link is placed after tags, the entire page will block and not display anything until the font is loaded."